# Difference between setInterval parameters

Tags: jquery, parameters, intervals

Please anybody tell me that what is the difference between the below setInterval methods. What is the best way to passing the function in the setInterval as a parameter.

```
function red_on(){
   $('#red_light').css('opacity', 1);
}

setInterval(function () {
   red_on();
}, 4000);

setInterval(red_on, 4000);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the first approach when you need to pass some parameters to the function, otherwise the second approach is more simple and readable.

Ex:

```
function red_on(opacity){
   $('#red_light').css('opacity', opacity);
}

setInterval(function () {
   red_on(1);
}, 4000);

setInterval(red_on, 4000); <-- Here you cannot pass parameters
```

Please see following snippet:

```js
function test(par1){
  console.log(par1);
}

setInterval(function () {
   test("message every 4 seconds");
}, 4000);

setInterval(test("message2: called just one time!"), 4000);
```

I hope it helps you. Bye.

Answer (score 1):

Last method is the best.

Basically in first method you are executing function (red_on()) inside of anonymous function. Ergo you have two functions.

Since setInterval is taking function as a first parameter you can just pass the function you want to execute without creating anonymous function.

If you want to do `red_on()` **and** something else (like console.log) then the first approach is better.

TL;DR There is no big difference.

Answer (score 0):

The second approach is the correct one in this case.  I would describe it as people.  If you want to talk to a person named Red_on in your second approach you are talking directly to Red_on.  The first approach you're still talking to Red_on but you pull in an anonymous function or another person to talk to them.  So while Red is still getting your message you're just adding another step in an anonymous function.

Answer (score 0):

There is no differences.

From performance persective second approach is better as you do not create anonimous function but use reference only. In first case you will create function twice to achieve the same result.